# Merging two or more columns from different SQL queries

Tags: sql, select, merge

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to **merge together two columns** with sql (I'm new at it). It should be really simple but I simply can't find a way to do it. I have two results from **two different selects statements**, and they both have the **same number of rows**, but **different columns**. I just want to "attach" all the columns together.

Example.
This is the first table:

[image: TrainerClass Table]

This is the second table:

[image: DescriptionTranlsation]

The following query:

```
SELECT [t].* FROM [TrainerClass] AS [t];
```

or simply

```
SELECT * FROM [TrainerClass];
```

will give the result shown here:

[image: Query number 1 result]

Now, the second query, which is:

```
SELECT [d].[Description] AS [Name] FROM [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d], [TrainerClass] AS [t] WHERE [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND [d].[FieldName] = 'Name' AND [d].[Code] = [t].[Code] AND [d].[Language] = 'en-EN';
```

will result in this table:

[image: Query number 2 result]

Pretty straight forward. Now, what I simply want to get is this:

[image: Final result]

Why is it so hard to me? What would you do to achieve that? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT [t].*,
       [d].[Description] AS [Name],
       [d2].[Description] AS [Description]
FROM   [TrainerClass] AS [t] join [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d] on [t].[Code] = [d].[Code]
       join [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d2] on [t].[Code] = [d2].[Code]
WHERE  [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND 
       [d].[FieldName] = 'Name' AND 
       [d].[Language] = 'en-EN' AND
       [d2].[FieldName] = 'Description'
```

Comment: Thank you, what if I had another column to add such as: 
SELECT [d].[Description] AS [Description] FROM [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d], [TrainerClass] AS [t] WHERE [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND [d].[FieldName] = 'Description' AND [d].[Code] = [t].[Code] AND [d].[Language] = 'en-EN' ? 
How would you do that?
Also, I'm using SQLite. I've tried your query and it doesn't seem to work. I'd really appreciate some help

Comment: What is the error message, and what extra column would you like to include?

Comment: The error is {"SQLite error\r\nnear \"FROM\": syntax error"}, but it turned out to be just an extra comma. I would like add a column similar to the one I already have but with another field, for example "Description". So that I have a variable number of parameters.

Comment: Basically I'd like to achieve something like: [d].[Description] AS [Name] (where [d].[FieldName] = 'Name'), joined with [d].[Description] AS [Description] (where [d].[FieldName] = 'Description'). Any ideas?

Comment: Here you go - I think this is what you want

Comment: It works partially, infact it returns both the languages. Probably the missing part is [d2].[Language] = 'en-EN'. Also, how could I make it work with n columns?

Answer (score 0):

I you have any common ID in your tables, you can use join as stated in answers, otherwise you can use union statement

Answer (score 0):

The below statement will allow you to join the 2 tables together on their common field(code)
Then you can simply select whatever you like from either table.

Hope this helps!

SELECT ID, Code, Name
FROM DescriptionTranslation join TrainerClass
     on DescriptionTranslation.Code = TrainerClass.Code