# SQL WHERE statements in SELECT statements

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, select, where-clause

I'm making a query which takes data from the rows of a table and puts it under the same column:

```
SELECT [t].*,
       [d].[Description] AS [Name],
FROM   [TrainerClass] AS [t] join [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d] on [t].[Code] = [d].[Code]
WHERE  [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND 
       [d].[FieldName] = 'Name' AND 
       [d].[Language] = 'en-EN';
```

This works just fine, but it returns a single column. I want to get the same result with more columns, but I can't figure out how to do it with the WHERE statements. I'd like to achieve something like:

```
SELECT [t].*,
       [d].[Description] AS [Name] WHERE [d].[FieldName] = 'Name',
       [d].[Description] AS [Info] WHERE [d].[FieldName] = 'Info',
FROM   [TrainerClass] AS [t] join [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d] on [t].[Code] = [d].[Code]
WHERE  [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND 
       [d].[Language] = 'en-EN';
```

I know it's not a proper syntax, and that's why I'm asking you how to get this result. Thank you in advance :)

EDIT:

What I don't want:

[image: No]

What I want:

[image: Yes]

(Examples made with only one record, there should be more)

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `CASE` statement like below (I think that is what you are looking for). Mind you, mismatching rows in each case will get null values or you can add the else part to the case statement.

```
SELECT [t].*,
       CASE WHEN [d].[FieldName] = 'Name' THEN [d].[Description] END AS [Name],
       CASE WHEN [d].[FieldName] = 'Info' THEN [d].[Description] END AS [Info]

FROM   [TrainerClass] AS [t] join [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d] 
                             on [t].[Code] = [d].[Code]
WHERE  [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND  --[d].[FieldName] = 'Name' AND 
       [d].[Language] = 'en-EN';
```

**UPDATE:**

As per your update, to get expected results from shown picture table, you can use `Max()` function with `Group by`:

```
;With cte as 
(
    --your first query goes here 
)
Select Id,Code, Max(Name) Name, Max(info) Info
from cte
Group by Id, Code
```

Of you can do without `CTE` as:

```
SELECT t.Id, t.Code,
       Max(CASE WHEN d.FieldName = 'Name' THEN d.Description END) AS Name,
       Max(CASE WHEN d.FieldName = 'Info' THEN d.Description END) AS Info
FROM   [TrainerClass] AS t join [DescriptionTranslation] AS d  on t.Code = d.Code
WHERE  d.TableName = 'TrainerClass' AND  --[d].[FieldName] = 'Name' AND 
       d.Language = 'en-EN'
GROUP BY t.Id, t.Code;
```

Comment: I want the values of the columns with the same Code to be on the same row. Is there an easy way to do it?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If you provide a fiddle and update your question with expected results, it would be easy to understand and work out.

Comment: Here, you can check out my previous answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19163001/merging-two-or-more-columns-from-different-sql-queries
Hope it helps. I'm also updating the question with the expected result.

Comment: Updated, can you check it out? This code is the best I found so far it's tot bad it doesn't work properly.

Comment: I've updated on how to get what you want from what you don't want.

Comment: How would I use both the queries combined?

Comment: Use a common table expression as per updated answer.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your request right, you'll need to join the table twice with different filters.

```
select t.*, dName.Description as [Name], dInfo.Description as [Info]
from TrainerClass t
join DescriptionTranslation dName
    on t.Code = dName.Code and dName.FieldName = 'Name'
join DescriptionTranslation dInfo
    on t.Code = dInfo.Code and dInfo.FieldName = 'Info'
where
    dName.TableName = 'TrainerClass' and dName.Language = 'en-EN'
    and dInfo.TableName = 'TrainerClass' and dInfo.Language = 'en-EN'
```

Comment: It looks right to me, but unfortunately it doesn't return any data. No syntax errors, though...

Comment: Try doing `left join` instead of just `join` (which is inner join by default). See if that gives you any hint as to why you're not getting a match.

Answer (score 1):

Another way you can use subqueries for your query and it's quite similar to your intention. But only one caveat with this method, that is it can be quite slow if you have large record-sets.

---

```
SELECT [t].*,
( SELECT [d].[Description]  FROM [DescriptionTranslation] [d] WHERE [d].[FieldName] = 'Name' and [t].[Code] = [d].[Code] [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND 
[d].[Language] = 'en-EN') AS [Name], 
(SELECT [d].[Description]  FROM [DescriptionTranslation] [d] WHERE [d].[FieldName] = 'Info' and [t].[Code] = [d].[Code] [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND 
[d].[Language] = 'en-EN') AS [Info]     
FROM   [TrainerClass] AS [t]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below `CROSS APPLY` for your query

```
SELECT  [t].*,
        [DTNameDescription].[Description] AS [Name]
        [DTInfoDescription].[Description] AS [Info] 
FROM    [TrainerClass] AS [t] 
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  [Description] 
            FROM    [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d] 
            WHERE   [t].[Code] = [d].[Code] 
                        AND [d].[FieldName] = 'Name'
        ) AS DTNameDescription
        CROSS APPLY (
            SELECT  [Description] 
            FROM    [DescriptionTranslation] AS [d] 
            WHERE   [t].[Code] = [d].[Code] 
                        AND [d].[FieldName] = 'Info'
        ) AS DTInfoDescription
WHERE   [d].[TableName] = 'TrainerClass' AND 
        [d].[Language] = 'en-EN';
```